# R sapply function ifelse variable comparison

Tags: r, function, variables, matrix

I'm trying to use `sapply` with `function(x,y)` to loop over my matrices..

```
test<-sapply(colnames(my_mat), function(x, y) ifelse (x==y,-1,cor(test_mat[,x],test_mat[,y], use="p")) )
```

Basically it calculates the correlation between each columns cells, but when they are both the same object, I want it to return -1 instead of 1. My matrix is set up like so:

```
   A B C
A  . . .
B  . . .
C  . . .
```

And I want the -1 on the diagonals.

I get an error saying `Error in x == y : 'y' is missing` but if I remove the `ifelse`, the code works fine (albeit has 1 in diagonals as opposed to -1). Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cor` is vectorised and has a method for matrices, so to acheive this all you really need to do is to compute the correlation of the matrix with itself, which gives the correlation between each column. Notice the matrix is symmetrical. Then just use `diag` to set the diagonal elements to `-1`...

```
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix( rnorm(25) , 5 )
#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
#[1,] -0.6264538 -0.8204684  1.5117812 -0.04493361  0.91897737
#[2,]  0.1836433  0.4874291  0.3898432 -0.01619026  0.78213630
#[3,] -0.8356286  0.7383247 -0.6212406  0.94383621  0.07456498
#[4,]  1.5952808  0.5757814 -2.2146999  0.82122120 -1.98935170
#[5,]  0.3295078 -0.3053884  1.1249309  0.59390132  0.61982575


cor.mat <- cor( m )
diag(cor.mat) <- -1
#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
#[1,] -1.0000000  0.2789049 -0.6149659  0.2491625 -0.7615458
#[2,]  0.2789049 -1.0000000 -0.7864121  0.5683647 -0.5313192
#[3,] -0.6149659 -0.7864121 -1.0000000 -0.6813702  0.9353307
#[4,]  0.2491625  0.5683647 -0.6813702 -1.0000000 -0.6429515
#[5,] -0.7615458 -0.5313192  0.9353307 -0.6429515 -1.0000000
```

To verify this is correct, check the correlation of the first column with all the other. You will see that the vector returned is the same as the first column of `cor.mat` above.

```
cor( m[,1] , m )
#     [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
#[1,]    1 0.2789049 -0.6149659 0.2491625 -0.7615458
```